# Check if field contains at least a number of digits

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, error-handling

Currently i am using the following script to check if my field is empty or not. For me this script works great, the only thing I want to add to the script is a check that the field needs at least 10 digits (numbers) in it too otherwise just shows the error message as in the script. I hope someone can help me find out what needs to be added to the code below

```
function checkforblank() {

var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('telefoonnummer').value == "") {
    errormessage += "your 10 digits phone number is missing " ;
    document.getElementById('telefoonnummer').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }


if (errormessage != "") {
    $(".error-messages").text(errormessage).fadeIn();
    return false;
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a plain length check on submit and the field can have only digits, you can use the below to check for length.

```
function checkforblank() {

    var errormessage = "";
    var inputVal = document.getElementById('telefoonnummer').value;
    if (inputVal == "") {
        errormessage += "your 10 digits phone number is missing " ;
        document.getElementById('telefoonnummer').style.bordercolor = "red";
    } 
    else if (inputVal != "" && inputVal.length !== 10) {
        console.log("error");
        //set your error message here
    } 
    else {
        console.log("success");
    }

    if (errormessage != "") {
        $(".error-messages").text(errormessage).fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Update**: Revised Version based on OP feedback - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/34P8A/)

Comment: I already build in a maxlength and a script that a user can only type numbers in the field.. I only want to check if the field contains 10 digits on submit within the code I posted with my question :)

Comment: no succes until now :( its still sending the form even though there are only 3 digits typed in the field

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren Please check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/34P8A/).

Answer (score 3):

Remove all non-digits and take the length

```
'a0b123c456v789---'
    .replace(/[^\d]/g, '') // "0123456789"
    .length;               // 10
```

Comment: This is clever but maybe someone would write `444-hello` which could be understood as `444-43556` (Ref, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#Key_Frequency)

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren you would replace `'a0b123c456v789---'` with the value of your input element, and check against the number you want (`10`), if false, append an explanatory error message

Comment: @NULL I wouldn't accept phone **numbers** written like that in a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //this is to check weather it is a number or not------
    function checkNumber(event,val){//use this function at keyup event of your field
    if(val.length <= 10) //check wether it is 10 digit or not
    {   
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
                     // Allow: Ctrl+A
                    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
                     // Allow: home, end, left, right
                    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                         // let it happen, don't do anything
                         return;
                }
                else {
                    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                    if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
         }

                       }   
                    }
            }
```

use the code with the your text field like this

```
<input type="text" id="phone" onkeyup = "checkNumber(event,this.value);" />
```